# What date format is this? How to convert it to standard format?

Tags: python, date, datetime

**44428.6628726736** translates to **16-11-2021  3:34:20 AM**. Got this from Samsung Health data.

Any idea what this format is and how to convert it? Excel converts it automatically to the given date but I want to be able to make this conversion in Python.

Comment: A Serial Date. In Excel that seems to be `20/08/2021 15:54:32` rather than your example? if thats correct see https://gist.github.com/OmarArain/9959241

Answer (score 0):

use xlrd to get the desired output from excel serial date format to datetime. Here is a sample,

```
import xlrd
xl_date = 44428.6628726736
datetime_date = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(xl_date, 0)
print(f"{datetime_date.date()} {datetime_date.time()}") 
tm_str = datetime_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(tm_str)
```

to get an equivalent output

```
2021-08-20 15:54:32.199000
08/20/2021 15:54:32
```